# index.php bloqueando servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, eu Baixei um script PHP gratuitamente com código fonte aberto e coloquei na pasta do meu servidor

Mas Ao entrar na página do index.php abre normal, mas ao abrir de novo ele não carrega e dá "erro de servidor" e bloqueia o meu servidor por 1 hora.

Eu queria muito esse script e até traduzir para português.

Código db.php

```html
<?php 
@mysql_connect("localhost","nome do banco de dados","senha do banco de dados") OR  die ("Erro Mysql!");
@mysql_select_db("nome do banco de dados")or die ("Erro de banco de dados");
?>
```

Código do index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("db.php");
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Ocorreu um erro! ".mysql_error());
$sor = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1254"/> 
<title>&lt;?php echo $sor[&#39;sitebasligi&#39;]; ?&gt;</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $sor['googleanahtar']; ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--->
<!--<script src="cssjs/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>--->
<link href="cssjs/includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="cssjs/styles/ticker-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="cssjs/includes/jquery.ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="cssjs/includes/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="cssjs/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cssjs/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cssjs/jquery.datepick-tr.js"></script>

<!-- Logo Bitiş --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker2').datepick();
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.blueberry').blueberry();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div#container
{
    position:relative;
    width: 959px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:left; 
}
body {text-align:center;margin:0}
img{ border:0; }
</style>
</head>
</head>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<body background="resimler/bg.jpg" style="background-attachment: fixed">
<div id="container">

<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from logo order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Hata Olustu! ".mysql_error());
$logo = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
?>

<!-- Logo Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1px; width:277px; height:101px; z-index:0">
<a href="index.php"><img border="0" src="admin/<?php echo $logo['logo']; ?>" width="277" height="101" alt=""></a>
</div>
<!-- Logo Bitiş --->

<!-- 7/24 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:513px; top:14px; width:310px; height:72px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/724.png" width="91" height="80" align="left"> <br>
<font style="font-style: italic" face="Tahoma" size="5"><?php echo $sor['ctel']; ?></font></div>
<!-- 7/24 Bitiş --->

<!-- Menü Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:122px; width:946px; height:57px; z-index:0">
<center>
<a href="index.php"><img src="resimler/menu1.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu11.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu1.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="arac-filomuz.php"><img src="resimler/menu2.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu22.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu2.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="transfer-hizmeti.php"><img src="resimler/menu3.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu33.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu3.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="kiralama-ucretleri.php"><img src="resimler/menu5.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu55.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu5.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="firma-hakkinda.php"><img src="resimler/menu4.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu44.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu4.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="bize-ulasin.php"><img src="resimler/menu6.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu66.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu6.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a></center>
</div>
<!-- Menü Bitiş --->

<!-- Slider alt başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:350px; width:580px; height:265px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/stand.png" width="530" height="140">
</div>
<!-- Slider alt bitiş --->


<!-- Slider Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:188px; width:626px; height:261px; z-index:0">

    <div class="blueberry">
      <ul class="slides">
<?php

echo "";
$sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sliderayarlari order by id DESC LIMIT 50");
while ($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sor)) {
$id = $listele['id'];
$slider = $listele['slider'];

echo " <li><img src=\"admin/$slider\" alt=\"\" width=\"440\" height=\"247\"/></li>";
}

echo "";

?>
</ul>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Slider Bitiş --->

<!-- Tarih1 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:513px; top:225px; width:215px; height:110px; z-index:0">
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="211" height="95" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td height="32" width="211" colspan="2">
            <img border="0" src="resimler/alis.jpg" width="200" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="20" width="200">
    <select size="1" name="D1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
    <option selected>-- Escolha o lugar --</option>
<?php

$kat_sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alis");
while($dongu = mysql_fetch_array($kat_sorgu)) 
{   
echo  "<option value='".$dongu["id"]."'>".$dongu["alis"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="21" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="21" width="200"><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="13" width="200">
<select name="D2" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px" size="1">
<option>06</option>
<option>07</option>
<option>08</option>
<option>09</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
</select>
<select name="alisil4" size="1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>

</select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="8" width="200">
&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Tarih1 Bitiş --->

<!-- Tarih2 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:730px; top:225px; width:215px; height:110px; z-index:0">
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="211" height="95" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td height="32" width="211" colspan="2">
            <img border="0" src="resimler/donus.jpg" width="200" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="20" width="200">
    <select size="1" name="D1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
    <option selected>-- Escolha o local de retorno --</option>
<?php

$kat_sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donus");
while($dongu = mysql_fetch_array($kat_sorgu)) 
{   
echo  "<option value='".$dongu["id"]."'>".$dongu["donus"]."</option>";
}
?>

    </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="21" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="21" width="200"><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="13" width="200">
<select name="D2" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px" size="1">
<option>06</option>
<option>07</option>
<option>08</option>
<option>09</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
</select>
<select name="alisil4" size="1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
</select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="8" width="200">
&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Tarih2 Bitiş --->

<!-- Hızlı randevu Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:515px; top:184px; width:430px; height:40px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/ustrandevu.png" width="428" height="35">
</div>
<!-- Hızlı randevu Bitiş --->

<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:515px; top:340px; width:250px; height:25px; z-index:0">
<center><input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON" checked> <b>
<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Todos Os Veículos</font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</center>
</div>

<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:750px; top:340px; width:193px; height:25px; z-index:0">
<a href="arac-filomuz.php"><img src="resimler/gonder.png"></a>
</div>



<!-- Duyuru Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:524px; top:370px; width:419px; height:32px; z-index:0">
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:524px; top:350px; width:419px; height:50px; z-index:0">
    <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">

<?php

echo "";

$sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM duyuru order by id DESC LIMIT 50");
while ($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sor)) {
$id = $listele['id'];
$duyurub = $listele['duyurub'];

echo " <li class=\"news-item\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Popup=window.open('duyuru.php?id=$id','Popup','scrollbars=yes, width=500,height=300'); return false;\"><font color=#FFFF00>$duyurub</font></a></font></b></li>";
}

echo "";

?>

    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Duyuru Bitiş --->
<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Ocorreu um erro! ".mysql_error());
$face = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
?>
<!-- facebook Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:550px; top:410px; width:400px; height:60px; z-index:0">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com.br/<?php echo $face['facebook']; ?>" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
<!-- facebook Bitiş --->



<!-- araclar Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:530px; width:970px; height:335px; z-index:0">

<?php
$sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM araclar order by rand() limit 4");
while ($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sor)) {
$id = $listele['id'];
$amm = $listele['amm'];
$kapi = $listele['kapi'];
$yolcu = $listele['yolcu'];
$bagaj = $listele['bagaj'];
$vites = $listele['vites'];
$klima = $listele['klima'];
$yakit = $listele['yakit'];
$birinci = $listele['birinci'];
$ikinci = $listele['ikinci'];
$ucuncu = $listele['ucuncu'];
$aracresmi = $listele['aracresmi'];


echo"
<div style=\"float:left; width:241px; height:275px\">
<table border=\"0\" width=\"221\" height=\"271\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td height=\"100\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <img src=\"admin/$aracresmi\" width=\"220\" height=\"123\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"18\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <p align=\"center\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" color=\"#000080\">$amm</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_kapi.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Kapı</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$kapi</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_yolcu.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Yolcu</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$yolcu</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_bagaj.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Bagaj</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$bagaj</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_vites.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Vites</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$vites</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_klima.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">Klima</font></b></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$klima</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_yakit.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Yakıt</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"6\">&nbsp;</td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$yakit</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"31\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <p align=\"center\">
        <a href=\"arac-detayi.php?id=$id\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/buton-detay.jpg\" width=\"102\" height=\"31\"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>";

}

echo "";

?>
</div>
<!-- veículos começados --->

<!-- döviz başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/moeda.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:65px; top:948px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/dolar-alis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:155px; top:948px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/dolar-satis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:65px; top:999px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/euro-alis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:155px; top:999px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/euro-satis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<!-- döviz bitiş --->


<!-- mesafe başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:240px; top:860px; width:240; height:205; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/distancia.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:282px; top:946px; width:200px; height:200px; z-index:0">
<iframe src="background-color=000000&font-size=0px&sonuc-color=f26522&sonuc-font-size=18px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="110" width="150"></iframe>
</div>
<link type="text/css" href="cssjs/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- mesafe bitiş --->


<!-- havadurumu başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:480px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/mensagem.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:520px; top:920px; width:150px; height:150px; z-index:0">
<?php include("botlar/hava.php");?>
</div>
<!-- havadurumu bitiş --->


<!-- S.S.S başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:720px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/sua-mente.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:735px; top:930px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<font face="Verdana" size="1" color="#FFFF00">
<?php

echo "";
$sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sss order by id DESC LIMIT 8");
while ($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sor)) {
$id = $listele['id'];
$sssb = $listele['sssb'];

echo "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Popup=window.open('sss.php?id=$id','Popup','scrollbars=yes, width=600,height=400'); return false;\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"1\" color=\"#FFFF00\">$sssb</font><a></li>";
}

echo "";

?>
</div>
<!-- S.S.S bitiş --->

<!-- alt başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1070px; width:960px; height:100px; z-index:0">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj2" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="950" height="90">
<param name="movie" value="resimler/alt.swf">
<param name="quality" value="High">
<embed src="resimler/alt.swf" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj2" width="955" height="90"></object>
</div>
<!-- alt Bitiş --->

<!-- footer başlangıç --->
<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("Hata Olustu! ".mysql_error());
$sor = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
mysql_close($link);
?>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1168px; width:960px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<font color=#000000 size="2" face="Verdana"><?php echo $sor['footer']; ?></font>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</div>
<!-- footer Bitiş --->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73237/discussion-on-question-by-angelino-index-php-bloqueando-servidor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A função `mysql_connect()` ficou obsoleta no PHP 5.5.0 e as funções `mysql_ *` foram removidas no PHP7!**

O PHP oferece as API mysqli e PDO para se conectar a um servidor MySQL.

Com [**MySQLi**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)  a conexão pode ser feita do seguinte modo:

**db.php**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "DB");
if ($link->connect_errno){
   die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
   exit();
}
```

E o index.php com **MySQLi** assim

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("db.php");

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = ("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$calistir);
$sor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1254"/> 
<title><?php echo $sor['sitebasligi']; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $sor['googleanahtar']; ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--->
<!--<script src="cssjs/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>--->
<link href="cssjs/includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="cssjs/styles/ticker-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="cssjs/includes/jquery.ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="cssjs/includes/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="cssjs/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cssjs/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cssjs/jquery.datepick-tr.js"></script>

<!-- Logo Bitiş --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker2').datepick();
    $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.blueberry').blueberry();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div#container
{
    position:relative;
    width: 959px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:left; 
}
body {text-align:center;margin:0}
img{ border:0; }
</style>
</head>
</head>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<body background="resimler/bg.jpg" style="background-attachment: fixed">
<div id="container">

<?php
$calistir = ("select * from logo order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$calistir);
$logo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>

<!-- Logo Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1px; width:277px; height:101px; z-index:0">
<a href="index.php"><img border="0" src="admin/<?php echo $logo['logo']; ?>" width="277" height="101" alt=""></a>
</div>
<!-- Logo Bitiş --->

<!-- 7/24 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:513px; top:14px; width:310px; height:72px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/724.png" width="91" height="80" align="left"> <br>
<font style="font-style: italic" face="Tahoma" size="5"><?php echo $sor['ctel']; ?></font></div>
<!-- 7/24 Bitiş --->

<!-- Menü Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:122px; width:946px; height:57px; z-index:0">
<center>
<a href="index.php"><img src="resimler/menu1.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu11.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu1.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="arac-filomuz.php"><img src="resimler/menu2.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu22.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu2.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="transfer-hizmeti.php"><img src="resimler/menu3.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu33.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu3.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="kiralama-ucretleri.php"><img src="resimler/menu5.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu55.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu5.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="firma-hakkinda.php"><img src="resimler/menu4.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu44.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu4.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a><img border="0" src="resimler/arasi.jpg" width="6" height="55" alt=""><a href="bize-ulasin.php"><img src="resimler/menu6.jpg" onmousemove="this.src='resimler/menu66.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='resimler/menu6.jpg'" width="152" height="55"/></a></center>
</div>
<!-- Menü Bitiş --->

<!-- Slider alt başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:350px; width:580px; height:265px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/stand.png" width="530" height="140">
</div>
<!-- Slider alt bitiş --->


<!-- Slider Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:188px; width:626px; height:261px; z-index:0">

    <div class="blueberry">
      <ul class="slides">
<?php
echo "";

$sor = ("select * from sliderayarlari order by id DESC LIMIT 50");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sor);
while($listele = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$id = $listele['id'];
$slider = $listele['slider'];

echo " <li><img src=\"admin/$slider\" alt=\"\" width=\"440\" height=\"247\"/></li>";
}

echo "";
?>
</ul>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Slider Bitiş --->

<!-- Tarih1 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:513px; top:225px; width:215px; height:110px; z-index:0">
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="211" height="95" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td height="32" width="211" colspan="2">
            <img border="0" src="resimler/alis.jpg" width="200" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="20" width="200">
    <select size="1" name="D1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
    <option selected>-- Escolha o lugar --</option>
<?php

$kat_sorgu = ("SELECT * FROM alis");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$kat_sorgu);
while($dongu = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{   
echo  "<option value='".$dongu["id"]."'>".$dongu["alis"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="21" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="21" width="200"><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="13" width="200">
<select name="D2" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px" size="1">
<option>06</option>
<option>07</option>
<option>08</option>
<option>09</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
</select>
<select name="alisil4" size="1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>

</select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="8" width="200">
&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Tarih1 Bitiş --->

<!-- Tarih2 Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:730px; top:225px; width:215px; height:110px; z-index:0">
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="211" height="95" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000" bordercolor="#000000">
        <tr>
            <td height="32" width="211" colspan="2">
            <img border="0" src="resimler/donus.jpg" width="200" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="20" width="200">
    <select size="1" name="D1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
    <option selected>-- Escolha o local de retorno --</option>
<?php

$kat_sorgu = ("SELECT * FROM donus");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$kat_sorgu);
while($dongu = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{   
echo  "<option value='".$dongu["id"]."'>".$dongu["donus"]."</option>";
}
?>

    </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="21" width="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="21" width="200"><input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20" width="11" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td height="13" width="200">
<select name="D2" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px" size="1">
<option>06</option>
<option>07</option>
<option>08</option>
<option>09</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>17</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>19</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>21</option>
<option>22</option>
</select>
<select name="alisil4" size="1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
<option>00</option>
<option>15</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>45</option>
</select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="8" width="200">
&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Tarih2 Bitiş --->

<!-- Hızlı randevu Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:515px; top:184px; width:430px; height:40px; z-index:0">
<img border="0" src="resimler/ustrandevu.png" width="428" height="35">
</div>
<!-- Hızlı randevu Bitiş --->

<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:515px; top:340px; width:250px; height:25px; z-index:0">
<center><input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON" checked> <b>
<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Todos Os Veículos</font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</center>
</div>

<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:750px; top:340px; width:193px; height:25px; z-index:0">
<a href="arac-filomuz.php"><img src="resimler/gonder.png"></a>
</div>



<!-- Duyuru Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; background:#000000; overflow:hidden; left:524px; top:370px; width:419px; height:32px; z-index:0">
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:524px; top:350px; width:419px; height:50px; z-index:0">
    <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">

<?php

echo "";

$sor = ("SELECT * FROM duyuru order by id DESC LIMIT 50");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sor);
while($listele = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{ 
$id = $listele['id'];
$duyurub = $listele['duyurub'];

echo " <li class=\"news-item\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Popup=window.open('duyuru.php?id=$id','Popup','scrollbars=yes, width=500,height=300'); return false;\"><font color=#FFFF00>$duyurub</font></a></font></b></li>";
}

echo "";

?>

    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Duyuru Bitiş --->
<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = ("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$calistir);
$face = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>
<!-- facebook Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:550px; top:410px; width:400px; height:60px; z-index:0">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com.br/<?php echo $face['facebook']; ?>" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
<!-- facebook Bitiş --->



<!-- araclar Başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:530px; width:970px; height:335px; z-index:0">

<?php

$sor = ("SELECT * FROM araclar order by rand() limit 4");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sor);
while($listele = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$id = $listele['id'];
$amm = $listele['amm'];
$kapi = $listele['kapi'];
$yolcu = $listele['yolcu'];
$bagaj = $listele['bagaj'];
$vites = $listele['vites'];
$klima = $listele['klima'];
$yakit = $listele['yakit'];
$birinci = $listele['birinci'];
$ikinci = $listele['ikinci'];
$ucuncu = $listele['ucuncu'];
$aracresmi = $listele['aracresmi'];


echo"
<div style=\"float:left; width:241px; height:275px\">
<table border=\"0\" width=\"221\" height=\"271\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
    <tr>
        <td height=\"100\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <img src=\"admin/$aracresmi\" width=\"220\" height=\"123\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"18\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <p align=\"center\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" color=\"#000080\">$amm</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_kapi.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Kapı</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$kapi</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_yolcu.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Yolcu</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$yolcu</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_bagaj.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Bagaj</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$bagaj</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_vites.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Vites</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$vites</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_klima.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"68\"><b><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">Klima</font></b></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"6\"></td>
        <td height=\"16\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$klima</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"28\" align=\"center\">
        <img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/icon_yakit.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"16\"></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"68\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>Yakıt</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"5\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\"><b>:</b></font></td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"6\">&nbsp;</td>
        <td height=\"19\" width=\"114\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">$yakit</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height=\"31\" width=\"221\" colspan=\"5\">
        <p align=\"center\">
        <a href=\"arac-detayi.php?id=$id\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"resimler/buton-detay.jpg\" width=\"102\" height=\"31\"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>";

}

echo "";

?>
</div>
<!-- veículos começados --->

<!-- döviz başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/moeda.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:65px; top:948px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/dolar-alis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:155px; top:948px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/dolar-satis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:65px; top:999px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/euro-alis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:155px; top:999px; width:120px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<p><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFF00" size="3"><?php include("botlar/euro-satis.php");?></font></p>
</div>
<!-- döviz bitiş --->


<!-- mesafe başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:240px; top:860px; width:240; height:205; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/distancia.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:282px; top:946px; width:200px; height:200px; z-index:0">
<iframe src="background-color=000000&font-size=0px&sonuc-color=f26522&sonuc-font-size=18px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="110" width="150"></iframe>
</div>
<link type="text/css" href="cssjs/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- mesafe bitiş --->


<!-- havadurumu başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:480px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/mensagem.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:520px; top:920px; width:150px; height:150px; z-index:0">
<?php include("botlar/hava.php");?>
</div>
<!-- havadurumu bitiş --->


<!-- S.S.S başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:720px; top:860px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<p><img border="0" src="resimler/sua-mente.png" width="240" height="199"></p>
</div>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:735px; top:930px; width:240px; height:205px; z-index:0">
<font face="Verdana" size="1" color="#FFFF00">
<?php

echo "";
$sor = ("SELECT * FROM sss order by id DESC LIMIT 8");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sor);
while($listele = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
$id = $listele['id'];
$sssb = $listele['sssb'];

echo "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"Popup=window.open('sss.php?id=$id','Popup','scrollbars=yes, width=600,height=400'); return false;\"><font face=\"Verdana\" size=\"1\" color=\"#FFFF00\">$sssb</font><a></li>";
}

echo "";

?>
</div>
<!-- S.S.S bitiş --->

<!-- alt başlangıç --->
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1070px; width:960px; height:100px; z-index:0">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj2" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="950" height="90">
<param name="movie" value="resimler/alt.swf">
<param name="quality" value="High">
<embed src="resimler/alt.swf" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj2" width="955" height="90"></object>
</div>
<!-- alt Bitiş --->

<!-- footer başlangıç --->
<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
$calistir = ("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
$results = mysqli_query($link,$calistir);
$sor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

?>
<div id="otokiralamascriptiv2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:1168px; width:960px; height:50px; z-index:0">
<font color=#000000 size="2" face="Verdana"><?php echo $sor['footer']; ?></font>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</div>

<?php
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<!-- footer Bitiş --->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```